Bitcoin balance lost
I had $134 worth of bitcoin, withdrew $34 from phantom to binance. my binance balance reflected but the one from phantom didn't appear yet. What might cause this problem? Will I loose the funds?

StackOverflow is not a place for this kind of questions. Look for Phantom's community server like Discord and ask for help there. Also your question is confusing to be honest. If your transferring the coins from Phantom to your Binance, of course you will no longer see that balance from your Phantom since you already had it in Binance.
